# Model class not found in file /var/www/html/projects/api/vendor.../src/Illuminate/Database/..HasRelationships.php on line 506

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, eloquent

All my apis work fine in localhost,i put it on live server (ubuntu 16.04) i am getting this error when i request GET for to get particular details of project i am getting this error.

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class &#039;App\Rewards&#039; not found in file /var/www/html/projectsfundingandsharing/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php on line 506
Stack trace:
  1. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError-&gt;() /var/www/html/projectsfundingandsharing/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php:506
```

for to get particular project i have many class model(i used laravel elequonet techniq)

this is my routes/api.php file

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Use App\Article;
Use App\Projects;
Use App\User;
Use App\Rewards;
Use App\Comments;
Use App\User_address;
Use App\Shipping_location;
Use App\ProjectController;
Use App\rewardsController;
Use App\storyController;
Use App\CommentsController;
use App\ActivationService;

//everything works fine when i call this api.
Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index');

//errors is occurring here when i trying get all relational models class.
Route::get('projects/{id}', function($id) {
   $project = Projects::with('rewardsProject.shippings','projectImage', 'projectFaqs','projectStory','userdetails', 'user.user_address')
          ->where('id', $id)
         ->get();
   return $project;
    //return Projects::find($id)->user->user_address; 
});
```

This is my projects model class

```
namespace App;
use App\Project_images;
use App\Comments;
use App\Rewards;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class Projects extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['title', 'video_url', 'pledged_amount', 'currency', 'end_date', 'funded_amount', 'percent_funded', 'funding_model', 'start_date', 'duration', 'category_id', 'category_name', 'user_name','user_id', 'total_backers', 'picture', 'links'];


   public function projectUser(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
   }


   public function projectStory(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Story');
   }
   public function projectFaqs(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Faqs');
   }

   public function projectRewd()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rewards','rewards', 'projects_id');
       // return $this->hasMany('App\Rewards');

   }

   public function projectShip()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shipping_location', 'shipping_locations','reward_id','project_id');
       //return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
   }

   public function projectImage()
   {  
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project_images');
   }


    public function rewardsProject(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Rewards');
    }
    public function userdetails(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id', 'user_id');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        //return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\User_address');
    }
}
```

THis is my rewards.php model class

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class rewards extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['amount', 'delivery_date', 'projects_id', 'quantity', 'backers_count', 'currency', 'contain_shipping_locations', 'title', 'description'];

   /*----*/
   public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Projects');
    }

    public function shippings(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shipping_location','rewards_shipping_location', 'reward_id', 'shipping_location_id');
    }




}
```

As like this i put all the correct model class.

please help me to why i am getting this erros, i put `App\Rewards` path in all the class file, and when i remove `rewardsProject.shippings` in routes/api.php file i am getting `App/Story not found`

Comment: have you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: yes i have done that, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class isn't named `App\Rewards` you named it `App\rewards`.

Linux is case sensitive. The autoloader looks for files based on the class name. The autoloader is now looking for `Rewards.php` not `rewards.php`. It can't autoload your class.

Always use the correct case when referencing classes even if PHP doesn't care, the autoloader has to load files, and filesystems can be case sensitive. Just always pretend case sensitive is a concern.

Comment: ok!! it works on windows xampp, errors occurs in ubuntu live server. Let me try to change the name of all model. May be that the problem occur, will try that, thanks Lagbox.